# Enter page number of some context in a sentence of a paragraph in MS Word document file

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, documents

I am writing an article that has too many pages. Still i am writing and page numbers change all the time. I want to mention some page numbers in my word file which exist at few page next to current page in sentence of a paragraph. Everyday page number change so I used to change the page number manually.

Is there any way to make it just like insert page number at footer? Please help me if there is an elegant way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the field function "PAGE" (on the ribbon go to Insert -> Quick Parts -> Field) as shown in this screenshot. This will add page dynamic numbers anywhere you want.

[image: screenshot add field in word]

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you need is a PageRef to a bookmark.

From Allen Wyatt on tips.net

Word includes the capacity to add cross-references to page numbers in your document. For instance, you can insert a field that will automatically refer to a bookmark on another page. If the page number containing the bookmark changes, the page number cross-reference changes as well. To insert a page number cross-reference, follow these steps:

Insert a bookmark on the page containing the information you want to cross-reference.

Position the insertion point where you want the cross-reference to occur.

Press Ctrl+F9 to insert field brackets. Make sure the insertion point stays between the brackets.

Type pageref followed by the bookmark name used in step 1.

Press F9 to update the field information.

https://word.tips.net/T000957_Inserting_Page_Number_Cross-References.html